# What happened to Sheldon's assistant, Alex?

Tags: character, the-big-bang-theory

In some episodes of Season 6, Sheldon had a young assistant named [Alex Jensen](http://bigbangtheory.wikia.com/wiki/Alex_Jensen). However, she did not appear in Season 7 nor 8. Is there any mention or explanation as to why she did not appear in later episodes?

Did she leave her job, or was she fired by Sheldon? On the other hand, does she still work for him, but we don't see her anymore?

I am looking for facts, not theories, I know that it is likely that she left because of the unmet love for Leonard or the sexual harassment committed by Sheldon, but is this mentioned anywhere in the series or by the creators? Will she reappear in a later episode?

[image]

According to Wiki:

> Alex's presence was to force Penny to realize that other smart and
>   pretty women are also interested in Leonard.

But there is no mention of what happened with her after season 6.

Comment: She was basically a one-note-joke, someone attractive to make Penny jealous and for Sheldon to be clueless at. I guess they just didn't see the need to continue showing her.

Comment: @Richard: I know that (see the end of my question), but she appeared in 4 or 5 episodes and not only one like some of the one-note-jokers, at least they could have added a sentence about her in a later episode where is mentioned what happend with her. And maybe they did and i just missed the episode...

Comment: I don't recall her being mentioned again but don't forget that in the following seasons they've dramatically changed the show's emphasis, focusing far more heavily on the supporting characters and basically giving them their own mini-spinoff show within the main show.

Comment: Maybe as an actress, or as a character she proved to be unpopular with viewers. Writers experiment with new characters all the time, and if they see a positive reaction they continue writing for those characters. Personally, I liked her, but after Leonard and Penny hooked up, what would have been her role? And what about Amy? Isn't there a scene where Amy marks her territory, e.g. she licks Sheldon's phone, so that Sheldon won't be physically attracted to Alex.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: Yes, as i mentioned there could be many reasons why she does not appear anymore. But i was hoping for facts, like a mention in the series or a statement of the creators or actors. Maybe there is no fact-based answer for this question, but i was hoping that someone knows something about this, it is a bit sad that she seems to be removed from the series without further mention, at least a one-line comment in a later episode of the series would have been nice...

Comment: If no one posts an answer, I'll take a shot at it (much) later in the day.

Comment: hanging out with Sheldon's sister or Raj's girlfriend ?

Comment: @guy_sensei she doesn't get paid enough to fly between texas and india often.

Comment: Instead of opting for independent female characters like Raj's sister or Alex, the writers decided to bring another co-dependent character like Amy when we already have one in the show i.e., Leonard.

Comment: Margo Harshman got a better role on NCIS

Answer (score 3):

It wasn't mentioned and probably won't be because it's not relevant to the narrative of the show.  She was introduced, served her purpose and was never heard from again (though one could infer that after the 'sexual harassment' episode that she up and quit).  As for will she return, probably not.  She was a plot device, it played out, and now she is no longer needed

Comment: She appeared in an episode after the "sexual harassment" one.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't Sheldon leave the university briefly once he gave up on String Theory?  It could then be inferred that she no longer had a valid posting and had to transfer elsewhere.  If still at university, she may appear in passing later.

Answer (score 1):

Alex would have been too much competition for Penny.  It also would have been too awkward for the writers to feature more of Alex without risk of hurting Penny's profile on the show.

Answer (score -2):

I've been thinking a lot about this, and have come to the only possible conclusion:

Penny killed Alex.

We all know Penny has a violent side. In 'The Dead Hooker Juxtaposition' she physically attacks an upstairs neighbor she barely knows just for asking about Leonard.

In 'The Speckerman Recurrence' she tells Amy and Bernadette that she tied up a girl and left her in a cornfield as a prank in highschool.

Perhaps most telling of all, in 'The Egg Salad Equivalency' she announces to Sheldon, Amy and Bernadette: "I'm gonna kill her!" when she discovers Alex has asked Leonard out.

I suspect Penny killed Alex when she left Sheldon's apartment on Valentine's Day, 2013 in 'The Tangible Affection Proof'. Although Alex was only helping Sheldon get Amy a gift, it's possible Penny thought Alex was trying to move in on Leonard again (even though he was still at work at the time).

Penny kills Alex (possibly with the baseball bat she wields in 'The Bozeman Reaction') and has just enough time to dump the body before getting ready for dinner.

Her aloof, manic and combative mood later that night at dinner with Leonard, Howard and Bernadette is a classic sign of her guilty conscience manifesting itself.

Comment: Well... that's pretty dark.